# How do I prevent the Google notifications from closing after losing focus?

Tags: google-plus

There is nothing I abhor more in social media than having my content deleted without warning.

Say I get a YouTube notification. I start writing a reply to someone who replied to me, and maybe I go to another window on my other monitor to look up additional information, or I simply misclick, but as soon as I do, **BAM**, I just lost the entire comment that I was writing.

Is it possible to open the Google notifications in a sort of sidebar, or use a Greasemonkey script to prevent it from closing, or change a setting to add a warning that I am about to lose my content? This has happened to my countless times and the worst part of using Google+.